# Need to call the classname inside jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I have created two classes for the option selector, one for connecting this to java script and another one for is a predefined class of bootstrap-select. But, when I am trying to use this both classes the selector is not loading. Can anyone help?

```
$(".selectiona").html(rows);-js called
```

.

```
<select id="selection" class="selectiona selectpicker" style="!important;"data-live-search="true" required="required" name="option" data-width="100%">
</select>
```

.

```
function manageRow(data) {
    var rows = '';
    rows = rows + '<option value="10" data-target="#create-item">Add New</option>';
    $.each( data, function( i, o ) {        
        rows += '<option>'+o.salary_wage+'</option>';    
    });  
    $(".selectiona").html(rows);    
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for the classes?

Comment: @Taplar Im using ajax to call the data to the jquery selector so i need to pass the select picker class into the js

Comment: @Muymuy1 select picker is a bootstrap class and the selectiona is the class im using to trigger the js function

Comment: Regarding your edit, have you got the JS directly inside a `<select>` element and *not* in a `<script>` element? That won't work even aside from any interaction with Bootsrap. The JS would have to appear in a `<script>` element included after the select element, and/or in a document ready handler.

Comment: @nnnnnn i had a small mistake when pasting the code here can you check now

Answer (score -1):

Don't do your function like this. Probably your script run but Selectpicker can run after that and remove whatever you do before. Just use Selectpicker API instead. When ever you use third plugin please use their API.